# Why is unused imports being imported

Tags: python, import

In the following sample why does running `a.py` require the bogus module when it's not being used at all in Foo?

a.py

```
from b import Foo

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(Foo.bar)
```

b.py

```
from bogus import bogus

class Foo:
    bar = "Hello World"

class Bar:
    def foo(self):
       bogus.bogus()
```

Comment: Why don't you delete line `from bogus import bogus` if it not used?

Comment: Added a class that uses bogus to clarify the case.